# Scaling vertices into a straight line

Tags: modeling, vertices

My background is in 3DS Max and I just started using Blender this week. Something I really liked about Max was the ability to quickly scale vertices into one uniform line using the scale too in order to be absolutely sure they were lined up for functions like extrusion and welding.

When I try to do the same thing in Blender, the vertices continue scaling along the axis in the opposite direction instead of becoming a straight line. The top screenshot shows the selected vertices (just as an example) and the bottom screenshots shows my attempt to scale them into one flat line across the x-axis; instead, they just end up scaling further down. Can someone help me with this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You got individual origins set as Pivot center for rotation/scaling,that's why you're getting this weird behaviour. Switch it to Median Point if you want vertices to make straight line in common middle.Check also other options. I find Active element very useful in similar cases.[image]

Answer (score 0):

For foolproof scaling, ensure your pivot center is '3D Cursor'. Select the vertices you wish to scale. Then hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, then 'Cursor to Selection'. The 3D cursor will be at the center of mass of your selected vertices.
Issue the Scale command <kbd>S</kbd>, then the axis you are scaling to (<kbd>X</kbd>, for instance), then simply type <kbd>0</kbd> (zero).